# XQuery with basex-node Database gives other results with an external variable?

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js, variables, basex

I am currently trying to get into properly using a BaseX Database in combination with the NodeJS package "[basex-node](https://github.com/apb2006/basex-node)".

By writing .js Scripts that connect to the BaseX-Database-Server that I have running on my local-machine, I was already able to create a new database, add and delete single files and messing around with some xquery-queries.

My problem is the following: When I use

```
var input = for $doc in collection(\'test_db\') where matches(document-uri($doc), \'test_db/a1.xml') return $doc;
var query = client.query(input);

query.execute(log.print);
```

to insert my query into a variable, bind it to a basex-node Query and execute it, I will get the contents of my document as a proper response, as I would expect.

Now what I want to do is to not have "a1.xml" as the fixed document I want to look for, but give an external variable instead. So I changed my code to the following:

```
var input = "declare variable $foo external; for $doc in collection(\'test_db\') where matches(document-uri($doc), \'test_db/$foo') return $foo";
var query = client.query(input);

query.bind("foo", "a1.xml", "", log.print);
query.execute(log.print);
```

So basically I use `$foo` as an external variable and bind "a1.xml" to it (I want to use that to later on find dynamic documents or specific nodes, as soon as I get to know how to use and call parameters with my .js script).

But the result I recieve when doing that is just "result:''" instead of the document.

I already tried changing the input to:

```
var input = "declare variable $foo external; return $foo";
```

And I recieved "result: 'a1.xml'", so I'm guessing I bound the variable in a correct way.

But it doesn't seem to work that way, so I assume I made either a huge mistake in understanding how all of this works, or a small stupid mistake in the code. Or maybe both.

Comment: Small hint: in XQuery, you can use both single quotes `'` and double quotes `"` to escape strings, they're equal. Saves you from escaping qutoes when constructing queries elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables are not resolved inside strings. Instead of `'test_db/$foo'` use `'test_db/'|| $foo`, which is shorthand for `concat('test_db/', $foo)`.

For example, this will return `foo$bar`

```
let $bar := 'bar'
return 'foo$bar'
```

while

```
let $bar := 'bar'
return 'foo' || $bar
```

will return the expected `foobar`.